# How to reset ringtone back in android programmatically

Tags: android, ringtone

I've used the following code to set the ringtone in my app which is working fine. Now i would like to provide the option to remove the ringtone and reset the ringtone back. Please help me on this. Thanks in advance.

```
            Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://"
                                + getPackageName() + "/raw/ringtone");
            RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(
                                getApplicationContext(),
                                RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, path);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After taking existingRingtonepath, you can set your custom ringtone path.

```
Uri existingRingtonePath = getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
```

After that you can use it to revert back.

```
RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(
                                getApplicationContext(),
                                RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, existingRinftonePath);
```

If you want to revert to default then,

```
RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(
                                getApplicationContext(),
                                RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, RingtoneManager.DEFAULT_RINGTONE_URI);
```